# Python Django Webapp is not responsive in smartphone

Tags: python, html, django, bootstrap-4, responsive

I have developed my first web app in python Django framework, deployed in pythonanywhere.com web server.

I have already used the latest bootstrap in this app, but it is not responsive properly on a smartphone screen. responsive in laptop and tablet but not in a smartphone.

You can also check it in your phone "http://sandeepbhatt.pythonanywhere.com/".

please look into my base.html and index.html code, where is the problem, also please let me know if there are any details required to figure out this problem which is not mention in this post.

**My base.html code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <title>PIV</title>
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/index.css" %}"> -->
</head>

<body>
  <!-- <style>
              body{ background: url("{% static "images/background.jpg"  %}");  background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat;}
            </style> -->

  <!-- Navbar start from here -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Navbar</a> -->
    <!-- Just an image -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'index' %}">
        <img src="{% static " images/logo.jpg" %}" width="70" height="50" alt="">
      </a>
    </nav>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">

        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
        </li>
        {% else %}
        <!-- <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'survey_app:user_login'%}">Login</a>
          </li> -->
        {% endif %}


        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'survey_app:analysis' %}">Analysis</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'survey_app:tracking' %}">Tracking</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">Admin</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'survey_app:register' %}">Register</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

</body>

<div class="container">
  {% block contant %}
  {% endblock %}
</div>
<!-- footer -->

<div class="card text-center">
  <div class="card-footer text-muted">
    Powered By <small>Political India Venture</small>
    &copy;2019
  </div>
</div>
</html>
```

**My index.html code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% extends 'survey_app/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block contant %}

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static " css/login_form.css" %}">
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
</head>

<!-- <style>
      body{ background: url("{% static "images/background.jpg"  %}");  background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat;}
    </style> -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <h2>Welcome to Political India Venture </h2>
    <h2>Survey App!</h2>

    <h5 class="font-italic<div class=" row">

      <h5>Get the answers you need</h5>

      <div class="wrapper">
        <form method="POST" class="form-signin" action="{% url " survey_app:user_login" %}">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {# A more "HTML" way of creating the login form#}
          <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please login</h2>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="User Name" required="" autofocus="" />
          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="" />
          <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me" id="rememberMe" name="rememberMe"> Remember me
          </label>
          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>


{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution after number of testing in my app and found there was only one bootstrap tag missing.
I just add this in my base.html file:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

and now it is proper responsive on every device.

Answer (score 0):

Your template is broken, look at `<h5> class-"font-italic` there is no closure (in index.html)